# jQuery("*").html; return unexpected result

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I am using google chrome, dev tools console and running jQuery("*").html; I want to see all the html code for the page appear in the console. But when I do so all I see is the following:

```
function (a){
if(a===b)return this[0]&&this[0].nodeType===1?this[0].innerHTML.replace(W,""):null;
if(typeof a=="string"&&!ba.test(a)&&(f.support.leadingWhitespace||!X.test(a))&&!be[(Z.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()]){a=a.replace(Y,"<$1></$2>");
try{
for(var c=0,d=this.length;c<d;c++) this[c].nodeType===1&&(f.cleanData(this[c].getElementsByTagName("*")),this[c].innerHTML=a)
}
catch(e){
this.empty().append(a)}
}
else 
f.isFunction(a)?this.each(function(b){var c=f(this);c.html(a.call(this,b,c.html()))}):this.empty().append(a);
return this
}
```

All I can think of is this might be somekind of security measure on the site in question that prevents people obtaining HTML markup?

Any ideas here would really help me :)

Comment: jQuery('html').html() use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

> jQuery("*").html();

. html() is a function not a property.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
jQuery('html').html()
```